# Use same selector in 2 components but different template syntax?

Tags: angular, angular-providers

I have 2 components (DetailPage, ListPage) with below template :

```
<my-detailpage>
 <my-header>{{ text }} </my-header>
 <my-content>{{ content }} </my-content>
</my-detaipage>

<my-listpage>
 <my-header>{{ text }} </my-header>
 <my-content>{{ content }} </my-content>
</my-listpage>
```

I want to use same selector for **header** and **content** ,but the different template base on detail page or list page.

I tried to do this with using **providers** but not sure if it's the right path.

Any help also good to me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jayanthCoder, I got your point and update my way for this trouble.

**my-header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-header',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>` ,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**my-detailpage.component.ts**

```
<my-detailpage>
    <my-header>Content for detail page : {{ text }} </my-header>
</my-detaipage>
```

**my-listpage.component.ts**

```
<my-listpage>
    <my-header>Content for list page : {{ text }} </my-header>
</my-listpage>
```

With this solution, I can keep structure of multi component with different case.

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute for my-header and my-content to differentiate.

```
<my-detailpage>
 <my-header pagetype="detailpage">{{ text }} </my-header>
 <my-content pagetype="detailpage">{{ content }} </my-content>
</my-detaipage>

<my-listpage>
 <my-header pagetype="listpage">{{ text }} </my-header>
 <my-content pagetype="listpage">{{ content }} </my-content>
</my-listpage>
```

Comment: Are there any ways to creating 2 components "my-header" and provider on different case ?

Comment: my-header is the same component. Just have an attribute specific to each detail page or listpage. Inside the code for my-header, check that attribute and specifically handle for each listpage or detail-page